# change the tomcat version 5.5.26 to 6.0.29?

Tags: java, tomcat6, java-6, tomcat5.5, java-5

Currently my server is running of the Tomcat 5.5.26 and JDK 1.5.15.
Now I want to change to tomcat 6.0.29 and JDK 1.6.29.

There was many application running of the current environment so if I can change to new environment the required to compile all the application again and upload on the new environment  or existing war file is working with new environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The applications *should* just work. However, you should do thorough testing of each one before inflicting them on your users, just to make sure. Your apps may be unintentionally relying on Tomcat 5-specific behaviour.

Furthermore, there should be no need to recompile under java 6 to make them work. However, you should check that the apps *do* still compile under Java 6. Again, they should, but it's worth checking.

Incidentally, why Tomcat 6?  Tomcat 7 is current stable version of Tomcat; if you're going to migrate, you should migrate to that.